# How to wrap a block element with link?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

As the [HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#example-e6ee3b01) states

> The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g., buttons or other links).

With this in mind, I have a WordPress PHP document starting with the HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`), and I'm wrapping a `<article>` with a `<a>`, and have set the `<a>` to `display: block`.

My source PHP:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <article>
        <header>
            Some header content
        </header>
        <footer>
            Some footer content
        </footer>
    </article>
</a>
```

But when I view it in several up-to-date browsers (tested in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari), I get this:

```html
<a href="the-correctly-rendered-url">
</a>
<article>
  <a href="the-correctly-rendered-url"></a>
  <header>
    <a href="the-correctly-rendered-url">
       Some header content
            </a>
  </header>
  <footer>
    Some footer content
  </footer>
</article>
```

The wrapping `<a>` gets moved completely outside of the `<article>`, and duplicated to wrap some elements inside of it.

Are these browsers just not adhering to HTML5 specs? What can be done if the rendered page doesn't seem to follow the given spec?

Comment: Can you show `the_url()`?

Comment: What you say you get in the browser is presumbly the DOM view? What does the actual HTML source code the browser received look like? Did your PHP script make this output directly, or is this maybe send through additional parsers/filters/whatever by a system outside of this script, CMS, wordpress, ...?

Comment: @AmmoPT I hid the actual php for this question, but the actual url part renders out correctly.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, it's a page in a Wordpress site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, some other custom & Wordpress functions were creating additional `<a>` tags, `project_categories_terms_links()` and `edit_post_link()`, inside the `<article>` tag which was causing the odd rendering.

Once I removed those or made them plain text, everything rendered as expected.

Hope this helps anyone coming across the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to the function [the_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/) which will contain filters and other stuff.

The code you posted works fine with a normal function that just echoes a string.

**Instead of using**

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
```

**Try using**

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
```

Comment: Apologies. I had reduced my question code to the essentials of the problem. In my production code I'm using `the_permalink();` which renders perfectly fine. It's the `<a>` tag that still doesn't wrap correctly—hence the actual problem at hand. I'll update my question to clarify.

Comment: @dmoz I updated the answer accordingly. Everything I said about `get_url()` stands for `get_permalink`, give it a go?

Comment: Tried it. It renders the url string the same(correctly) as the method I was already using, but the wrapping problem still exists.

Answer (score -1):

you can try

```
    <article>
      <a href="<?php the_url(); ?>">
         <header>
            Some header content
         </header>
         <footer>
            Some footer content
        </footer>
      </a>
    </article>
```

Answer (score -1):

I just tested your code using this simple example and it works well in my browsers

```
<?php
    function the_url()
    {
        echo 'http://exemple.com';
    }
?>

<a href="<?php the_url(); ?>">
    <article>
        <header>
            Some header content
        </header>
        <footer>
            Some footer content
        </footer>
    </article>
</a>
```

The output

```
<a href="http://exemple.com">
    <article>
        <header>
            Some header content
        </header>
        <footer>
            Some footer content
        </footer>
    </article>
</a>
```

Your problem is somewhere else

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: Could you provide more code than the wrapper itself because as stated the code you provided is working as expected. The problem is not in the code you provided, it is elsewhere. It is my belief that you are mistaken by thinking the problem is the browser not being able to follows HTML5. I think it is not. In order for me or anyone else to help you, more code is needed.